# Проблема в собранном JavaFX артефакте

Tags: java, javafx

*Доброго времени суток*
Столкнулся с проблемой когда собрал JavaFX артефакт.
В появившемся окне в поле `TextArea` не выводится текст вопросов при том что в отладке внутри IntelliJ IDEA текст отображается.
  Вопросы загружаются из текстового файла.[image: Скрин роботы артефакта]

[image: Работа в отладке IntelliJ IDEA]

[image: Архитектура проекта]

Код загрузки вопросов из файла:

```
private String[] fillQuestionsFromFile(){
    String[] questionsList = new String[90];

    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/PsychoTest/main/Resourses/Questions.txt"))){
        int i = 0;
        String question;

        while ((question = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            questionsList[i] = question;
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Не открывается файл с вопросами!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return questionsList;
}
```

Вызов метода и использование:

```
private String[] questions;
```

...

```
questions = fillQuestionsFromFile();
    tfQuestionNumber.setText("Вопрос " + (questionIndex+1));
    taQuestion.setText(questions[questionIndex]);
```

Comment: Приведите код, в котором происходит загрузка вопросов из файла.

Comment: @post_zeew `    private String[] fillQuestionsFromFile(){
        String[] questionsList = new String[90];

        try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/PsychoTest/main/Resourses/Questions.txt"))){
            int i = 0;
            String question;

            while ((question = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                questionsList[i] = question;
                i++;
            }

        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return questionsList;
    }`

Comment: Попробуйте переместить файл в корень проекта и считывать его так: `new FileReader("Questions.txt")`.

Comment: @post_zeew не помогло, перепробовал самые разные варианты.

Comment: @Trapping артефакт представлен jar-файлом? Если да, то замените FileReader на InputStreamReader и поток берите из getClass().getResourceAsStream("relative path")

Comment: @rvit34 получилось но кодировка сбилась. Какую кодировку для текстового файла использовать?

Comment: @rvit34 все, кодировка ANSI подошла. Благодарен за помощь)